# How to solve an integratation involved an unknown function?

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

Can anyone have any suggestions how to solve this equation for $w_i$, that is, what is the solution of $w_i$?
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)ε_i}P(r_i│ε_i )f(ε_i )dε_i=δ
$$

Where, $f(ε_i)$ is the probability density function of $ε_i$, $ε_i$ can be exponential random variable, $\Phi^{-1}(w_i)$ is the inverse of the normal CDF, $P(r_i│ε_i )$ is an unknown function, and all the remaining parameters are constant. I know it may not be possible to have an exact solution. However, there might have some approximation or clever trick, or possibility to get upper and lower limit of $w_i$. Thank you I appreciate your help :)

Or, can we write the above equation as
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)ε_i}P(r_i│ε_i )f(ε_i )dε_i=δ\int_0^\infty f(ε_i )dε_i
$$
and hence by cancelling out the integrations from the both sides
$$
e^{\Phi^{-1}(w_i)ε_i}P(r_i│ε_i )=δ
$$ 
because $\int_0^\infty f(ε_i )dε_i=1$

Comment: I suggest you use mathjax to typeset the math, because this is unreadable.